# Why can't September directly go to 2167 and talk to Dr.Oslo instead of coming back to 2015 and interact with Dr.Walter?

Tags: fringe

September might have learned about fatherly affection when he first saw Dr.Walter literally jumping across worlds to save his own son. But in order to hide Michael why bring him back to 2015 rather than going back to 2167 directly to Dr. Oslo? That way, nothing would have changed and there would not have been any Observers to invade back in 2016.

Am i missing something here?

Answer (score 7):

September didn't know what to do with Michael - essentially committing suicide by going to Oslo was not at the top of his mind.  He brought Michael to some time between 1979 and 2009, [and Michael was stuck there until the Fringe team found him in 2009](http://fringe.wikia.com/wiki/Inner_Child).

By the time September even realized a plan to stop the other Observers was necessary, he was stuck in 2012 with no access to time travel equipment.  Even then, he didn't really know what to do; [Walter was the one who came up with the plan, with assistance from September](http://fringe.wikia.com/wiki/Walter%27s_Plan).

Answer (score 0):

September had not thought about stopping the Observers in the first place. Considering from his point of view, the Observers chose to attack directly after the 12 observers had completed their observation of the past. The 12 observers were simply told to observe the past, and had not been told the real intention behind it. Because of this, September had no reason to suspect foul play. When he found out about the Observer's real plan, he took his child back to a time when the Observers hadn't invaded, and so that the original timeline would have enough time(between 1979 to 2015). Later, as he got acquainted of Dr.Walter, he and Walter planned all this out.